# get last update of a pip package programatically

Tags: python, automation, pip

( Apologies for an issue with the initial title of this question due to a copy paste issue)

On pypi.org I can search for packages by relevance or by "Date last updated"

What I'd really like to search for is by relevance and "Date last update" less than (for example) a year ago.

As the web frontend doesn't provide this I thought about writing a small script doing this for me.

Basic idea: 
 - call pip search "name"
 - parse the output and get via an api the last changed date and filter if too old
 - try to find a way to determine the relevance (perhaps just with https://pypi.org/search/?q=searchword )

cross both results.

So does anybody know how to get the last change date on pypi.org for a  given python package (or list of packages)?

Comment: https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (in particular because the title of my post suffered a copy past accident and was completely inappropriate). 

WIll look at warehouse.

Comment: "Warehouse" is the code-name for the current backend behind PyPI.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.


`https://pypi.org/pypi/<project_name>/json` 

returns a json and 
`json["releases"][release_id][integer_index]["upload_time"]` is exactly what I need.

If you post that as answer I can choose it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [JSON API](https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/json/). Projects don't have last modification date but releases have upload timestamp. So it's

```
json["releases"][version][package_index]["upload_time"]
```