# search pypi packages programatically (ideally sorted by relevance)

Tags: python, pip, pypi

This question is related to another question, that I posted [get last update of a pip package programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786395/get-last-update-of-a-pip-package-programatically)

I'd like to search packages with a given name on pypi. The interactive web page uses:
`https://pypi.org/search/?q=<search_word>`

but returns html.

Though I could use html parsers to extract information I wonder whether there is any other API to do this kind of search.

Skimming through https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/ I found how to get information about a given package (  https://pypi.org/pypi//json ) and how to get a list of all packages (  https://pypi.org/simple/ ) but I didn't find the way to search.

Comment: Well I mean by relevance ;-) 
More seriously I mean what is called "Relevance" on the pypi.org site. and what is the default order returned by searches on the web site.

On pypi.org you can order your results by one of the following "Relevance", "Date Last Updated", or "Trending"

Relevance is the default order. 
and this is what you get with `https://pypi.org/search/?q=<search_word>`
order for "Date Last Updated" can be done with `https://pypi.org/search/?q=<search_word>&o=-created` and order by trending with `https://pypi.org/search/?q=<search_word>&o=-zscore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyPI offers the ability to search via the XML-RPC API, see the `search` method here: https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/xml-rpc/. This is what the `pip search` command uses.

Unfortunately this is pretty limited, unwieldy, and will eventually be deprecated. There's a feature request for a proper search API here: https://github.com/pypa/warehouse/issues/5231, feel free to add a comment describing your needs.

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't even look at the XMP-RPC API as it is marked to be obsoleted and as they suggested to not use it for any new project.

Comment: Is there any non obsolete way to search? I'm afraid no as you mention a feature request, but I want to be sure

Comment: Nope, there isn't, sorry! But you can use the XML-RPC API for now.

Comment: by the way. Added a comment to the feature request. but does it make sense to comment on a feature request, that was closed over a year ago?

Comment: @gelonida Not sure what you mean, the issue is still open.

Comment: My bad was reading too quickly: I just saw a big red 'closed' tag a few lines above, but this was in fact for another ticket (Switch to pkgutil namespace package for svg #24)

Hope my (feenes')  explanation why this would be useful is understandable